# jQuery code to allow numeric input only for Android

Tags: android, jquery, character

I have the following code to allow only `numeric` values to be entered in a form's input field:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="qtty" size="2" value="1" class="numOnly" />
```

Javascript:

```
var allowedKeys = [8, 9, 13, 27, 37, 39,
    48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57
];
// 8 = backspace; 9 = tab; 13 = enter; 27 = escape; 37 = left; 39 = right;
// 48-57 = 0-9
$(".numOnly").keypress(function(event) {
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if ($.inArray(charCode, allowedKeys) == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
});
```

This works on the desktop `(Chrome, Firefox)` but not on `Android (Chrome)`. On the latter some keystrokes including all alphanumerics (`both upper and lower case`) are passed on to the textbox, as well as some special characters (`e.g. $, %`) while other special characters (`e.g. &, @`) are not.

Why is this, an what can I do to make the above code work on mobile platforms as well?

Comment: you can use `input type='number'` http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html

Comment: @Sushi: this does not explain why the quoted jQuery snippet behaves the way it does on Android. Also, type=number does not offer equivalent behavior, e.g. allows decimal points.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML  inputbox using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

if you are like me and HATE decimal points use this:

```
$(".vinput").on("input change paste",
function filterNumericAndDecimal(event) {
    var formControl;
    formControl = $(event.target);
    var newtext = formControl.val().replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");
    formControl.val(''); //without this the DOT will not go away on my phone!
    formControl.val(newtext);
});
```

if you need the dot included use [^0-9.] as regex

couple of things I found
-keypress is not working on mobile ..
-listening to keyup event is too late for calling preventDefault, but nevermind because preventDefault does not work on android ..